# C# Regex Matching Whole Word with MetaChars in

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

Im struggling a little to get the Regex correct for the search term

```
DESC + 7%
```

which is in my source data:

```
DESC          SFD        (HZ)

WGT.     15,000  LENGTH   15.00

LDWGT.     22,000          BBDESC + 7%o

GWGT     37,000                          ABAB

DESC + 7%        39,590               LLL

QA       SS SDB
```

I can see I need to escape the + and % which I have and I only want to match the whole word, not when its part of another.

Heres my current regex string, but it doesnt seem to match?

```
\bDESC \+ 7\%\b
```

Does anyone have any pointers as to why? I think its something to to with the closing \b but not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a upper B at the end:

```
\bDESC \+ 7\%\B
```

Example:

- in string "ADESC + 7%Z" result is ""
- in string " DESC + 7% " result is "DESC + 7%"

You cannot use \b on the end of the regex string because % character is a not word character.
When you search a "DESC + 7" without % character you can use your regex string.

Comment: Great answer, many thanks! works and I understand what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The second `\b` is wrong because this anchor matches with a transaction of a non-word-character to a word-character, *and vice versa* (`\W`->`\w` or `\w` -> `\W`)

In your pattern you have the snippet `\%\b`. The character `%` is not a word-character (and the next character isn't either), so the anchor **word-boundary** (`\b`) will never match here.

I think just removing it would work pretty well... See example [here](http://regex101.com/r/gM7wS6)

```
\bDESC\s\+\s7\%
```

Comment: Thanks Caio, your response also helped me understand why my expression was incorrect :)